How to implement intrinsic parameter calibrated to PMD Flexx 2
I am using PMD Flexx 2 with Ros 1. The package does not have anywhere to modify the lens parameter, as it says it reads from the camera module. Below is the lensParameters.hpp file. I found it from somewhere that says "The PMD flexx 2 comes factory calibrated with camera intrinsics and distortion parameters burned into its ROM". My questions is, is it not possible to change the intrinsic parameter etc for the PMD Flexx 2 camera? Thank you!
#pragma once

#include <royale/Pair.hpp>
#include <royale/Vector.hpp>

namespace royale {
/**                                                                                                                                           
 *  This container stores the lens parameters from the camera module                                                                          
 */
struct LensParameters {
    royale::Pair<float, float> principalPoint;       //!< cx/cy                                                                               
    royale::Pair<float, float> focalLength;          //!< fx/fy                                                                               
    royale::Pair<float, float> distortionTangential; //!< p1/p2                                                                               
    royale::Vector<float> distortionRadial;          //!< k1/k2/k3                                                                            
};
} // namespace royale

